# HTML template not working immediately after downloading

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded the Parallax Template on [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp) website. I downloaded the template by going to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_parallax.htm) and hitting Ctrl+S. I can't find the images in the background of the template anywhere. I tried modifying the code to try putting another image in place of the original parallax images but it did not work. I have very limited programming knowledge. Can you please help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Images might be treated as backgrounds in CSS. You should check your stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the CSS uses some relative URLs:

```
/* First image (Logo. Full height) */
.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url('/w3images/parallax1.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Second image (Portfolio) */
.bgimg-2 {
    background-image: url("/w3images/parallax2.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}

/* Third image (Contact) */
.bgimg-3 {
    background-image: url("/w3images/parallax3.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

When it is on w3schools.com, the URLs will go to locations like this:

```
https://w3schools.com/w3images/parallax1.jpg
```

But because it is no longer on that domain and is now on your file system, it will go to:

```
file:///w3images/parallax1.jpg
```

To fix this, simply change the code to the following:

```
/* First image (Logo. Full height) */
.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url('https://w3schools.com/w3images/parallax1.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Second image (Portfolio) */
.bgimg-2 {
    background-image: url("https://w3schools.com/w3images/parallax2.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}

/* Third image (Contact) */
.bgimg-3 {
    background-image: url("https://w3schools.com/w3images/parallax3.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

You will find this on lines 28-44 of the main HTML file.

---

This is not part of the question, but you also want to fix your icon font. On lines 9-11 of your main HTML file, you will find something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./W3.CSS Template_files/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./W3.CSS Template_files/css(1)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./W3.CSS Template_files/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Note that it may be slightly different depending on what browser you saved it with (I'm on Chrome).

You will not need to modify these assets, and they are actually hosted online-  It's just that your browser tries to be smart and download them for you. However, this will create a whole plethora of problems - in this case, your icon font will not show up correctly.

You will want to replace it with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

---

## TL;DR

In your main HTML file, replace lines 28-44 with:

```
/* First image (Logo. Full height) */
.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url('https://w3schools.com/w3images/parallax1.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Second image (Portfolio) */
.bgimg-2 {
    background-image: url("https://w3schools.com/w3images/parallax2.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}

/* Third image (Contact) */
.bgimg-3 {
    background-image: url("https://w3schools.com/w3images/parallax3.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

And lines 9-11 with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

---

There we go! Now everything should be working.

Answer (score -2):

If you will use Mozilla firefox then please press right click and click "view page info" after you have to press second tab "media" there you can download all background image with full path.